# Как использовать @extend стилей из другого SCSS файла и есть ли в этом смысл?

Tags: css, вёрстка, sass, scss

Заранее прошу прощения если этот вопрос уже задавался, но, несмотря на обширное кол-во информации по теме, найти ответа на свой вопрос я не смогла.

Суть в следующем:
Например, у меня есть два отдельных scss файла - header.scss и footer.scss. Стили футера почти полностью совпадают со стилями хедера, за исключением пары свойств.
Но если я прописываю в файле footer.scss @extend header - стили хедера не могут использоваться, т.к. это другой файл.

Подскажите, как идеологически вернее делать в данной ситуации? Чтобы новый класс/элемент получал стили существующего класса из другого файла + добавлял свои или менял некоторые стили на свои.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все что нужно, импортировать один файл в другой:

```
// header.scss
.header {
  ...
}

// footer.scss
@import 'header.scss';

.footer {
  @extend .header;
}
```

Идеологически правильным будет в корневой файл импортировать нужные файлы в последовательности при которой файл с расширяющими стилями будет импортироваться раньше чем файл в котором эти стили будут применяться:

```
// header.scss
.header {
  ...
}

// footer.scss
.footer {
  @extend .header;
}

// main.scss
@import 'header';
@import 'footer';
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ! Т.е. если сейчас у меня gulp автоматически собирает все scss файлы и сразу же конвертирует их в общий файл main.css - это не верный подход? Нужно сначала прописать в файле main.scss импорт всех файлов-стилей компонентов, а уже main.scss через gulp конвертировать их в css? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @VostrikovaVera, да, все верно. Если используете `watcher`, а не вручную пересобираете, то отслеживаете все *.scss файлы на предмет изменений и если один из них изменился, но все равно собираете файл в котором эти файлы импортируются (main.scss)